# android bug with textview

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have an activity MarkerDetailedActivity that should display all the information about the marker (photo / date / author / description / title). The problem is that the code thinks that `mDateTextView` is `mDescriptionTextView`. But in the xml file everything is written correctly.

Screen of my xml design

[image]

**MarkerDetailedActivity.class**

```
public class MarkerDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String EXTRA_MARKER = "marker";

public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, Marker marker) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MarkerDetailsActivity.class);
    startIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MARKER, marker);
    return startIntent;
}


ImageView mImageView;

TextView mNameTextView;

TextView mAuthorTextView;

TextView mDateTextView;

TextView mDescriptionTextView;

Marker mMarker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_marker);
    mMarker = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MARKER);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(mMarker.getName());
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });


    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mDateTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
    mAuthorTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_author);
    mDescriptionTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
    bindMarker(mMarker);
}

private void bindMarker(Marker marker) {
    Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext())
            .load(marker.getImage().getUrl())
            .into(mImageView);
    mAuthorTextView.setText(marker.getAuthor());
    mDescriptionTextView.setText(marker.getDescription());
    mDateTextView.setText(marker.getDate());
  }
}
```

And this is my xml file **activity_details_marker.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="224dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:src="@drawable/imag0162" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_black_gradient"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_a400"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                tools:text="Danik Fedirko" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_a400"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                tools:text="2018/02/02" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor si amet"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: the code thinks that mDateTextView is mDescriptionTextView.--> Can you please explain more. Are you getting any error

Comment: please add your log for more information.

Comment: No I do not have any error. As I said, this class displays information about the marker. But on the place of the description, the date appears, the name appears on the place of the author.

Comment: you need to check in marker object against the variable values accordingly.  check date and discription variables values what are inside them

Comment: then please check your text view id given by in XML file

Comment: are you using Instant Run? If yes, then disable it, rebuild project and never use it anymore.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question. In android studio design everything is all right but when I'm compile on a real device text views are beginning to change

Answer (score 0):

Check your model class Marker.
You make access date method like:

```
String date;
String description;
public String getDate(){
return description;
}
```

Or u may be setting description in date method

```
String date;
String description;
public void setDate(String s){
description = s;
}
```

Or vice versa

The best way is not right click on the blank screen in class and out of any method and select getter and setter.

Comment: Evrything is OK. I added a screenshot to my question. In android studio design everything is all right but when I'm compile on a real device text views are beginning to change

Answer (score 0):

Check your marker instance from where you are passing it as parcel able. You must be passing description in date property. Make sure you are passing right values in marker objects properties.

Comment: Evrything is OK. I added a screenshot to my question. In android studio design everything is all right but when I'm compile on a real device text views are beginning to change